# How to get ListView data from one activity to another using setOnClickListener

Tags: java, android, listview, nullpointerexception, onitemclick

In my listview there are to feilds,ward number and the date.i want to get these data to new activity when i'am clicking a listview.but in this there is a runtime error and i have no idea to how to fix it.

this is my dashboardActivity.java file,

```
public class DashboardActivity extends ListActivity implements FetchDataListener{

    UserFunctions userFunctions;
    Button btnLogout;
    TextView resultView;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    //private String email;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    /**
     * Dashboard Screen for the application
     * */        
    // Check login status in database
    userFunctions = new UserFunctions();
    if(userFunctions.isUserLoggedIn(getApplicationContext())){
        setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);

        initView();   

         ListView lv = getListView();

          // listening to single list item on click
          lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

                // selected item
              TextView txtviewWard= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ward_number);
              String ward = txtviewWard.getText().toString();

              TextView txtviewDate= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date_time);
              String dateTime = txtviewDate.getText().toString(); 

                // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListItem.class);
                // sending data to new activity
                i.putExtra("ward", ward);
                i.putExtra("dateTime", dateTime);
                startActivity(i);

            }
          });

        btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);

        btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                userFunctions.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(login);
                // Closing dashboard screen
                finish();
            }
        });

    }else{
        // user is not logged in show login screen
        Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
        login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(login);
        // Closing dashboard screen
        finish();
        }
    }

private void initView() {
    // show progress dialog
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...");

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String email = intent.getStringExtra(LoginActivity.EMAIL);


    String url = "http://pubbapp.comze.com/pubapp1.php?email=" + email;
    FetchDataTask task = new FetchDataTask(this);
    task.execute(url);


}


public void onFetchComplete(List<Application> data) {
    // dismiss the progress dialog
    if(dialog != null)  dialog.dismiss();
    // create new adapter
    ApplicationAdapter adapter = new ApplicationAdapter(this, data);
    // set the adapter to list
    setListAdapter(adapter);        
}


public void onFetchFailure(String msg) {
    // dismiss the progress dialog
    if(dialog != null)  dialog.dismiss();
    // show failure message
    Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();        
}

}
```

this is my SingleListItem.java file,

```
public class SingleListItem extends Activity{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item_view);

    TextView txtWard = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ward_number);
    TextView txtDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date_time);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    // getting attached intent data
    String wardNumber = i.getStringExtra("ward");
    String dateTime = i.getStringExtra("dateTime");
    // displaying selected product name
    txtWard.setText(wardNumber);
    txtDate.setText(dateTime);

}
```

this is my xml file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ward_number"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:text="wardNumber"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="25dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date_time"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Date"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="20dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is the error in the LogCat,

```
12-02 19:10:01.100: E/AndroidRuntime(22705): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-02 19:10:01.100: E/AndroidRuntime(22705): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-02 19:10:01.100: E/AndroidRuntime(22705):    at com.example.androidhive.DashboardActivity$1.onItemClick(DashboardActivity.java:59)
12-02 19:10:01.100: E/AndroidRuntime(22705):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
12-02 19:10:01.100: E/AndroidRuntime(22705):    at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3745)
12-02 19:10:01.100: E/AndroidRuntime(22705):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1980)
12-02 19:10:01.100: E/AndroidRuntime(22705):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-02 19:10:01.100: E/AndroidRuntime(22705):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-02 19:10:01.100: E/AndroidRuntime(22705):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-02 19:10:01.100: E/AndroidRuntime(22705):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
12-02 19:10:01.100: E/AndroidRuntime(22705):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-02 19:10:01.100: E/AndroidRuntime(22705):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-02 19:10:01.100: E/AndroidRuntime(22705):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
12-02 19:10:01.100: E/AndroidRuntime(22705):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
12-02 19:10:01.100: E/AndroidRuntime(22705):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

please help me to fix this error.
thank you.

Comment: I didnt't read through the code but what about simply usign an `Intent`?

Comment: `how to fix it` : read the stacktrace. check the indicated line. wonder why this exception happens at this specific line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first activity, pass the data as a bundle using [putExtras](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtras%28android.os.Bundle%29):

```
// sending data to new activity
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("ward", ward);
b.putString("dateTime", dateTime);
i.putExtras(b);
```

In second activity, retrieve the bundle and parse the data as follows:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
if (b != null) 
{
    String wardNumber = b.getString("ward");
    String dateTime = b.getString("dateTime");
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply.i changed that as you mentioned.but still there is same error.

Answer (score 0):

try this....

```
   ListView lv = getListView();

  // listening to single list item on click
  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {

       //your code

    }
  });
```

Comment: you used new OnItemClickListener() and mine is new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()..try this..it will work for sure

Comment: @user2881604 can you able to fetch data inside AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()..? make log and check first you getting value from adapter before starting activity. Then you can able find out issue

Answer (score 0):

get data like this in ur second activity:

```
Bundle b = savedInstanceState.getExtras();
    if(b!=null)
    {
        String ward =b.getString("ward");
        String dateTime =b.getString("datetime");

    }
```

bundle is responsible to getexras(),so use this.it worked for me and my other friends.